# gps doesn't provide my longitude and latitude accurately Android?

Tags: android, gps

I am usin location service for getting latitude and longitude of my location.While running my program it will give me wrong latitude and longitude.How can i get my current location details accurately? Is there any settings in mobile /device ?

```
String locationProvider = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;
        if(!locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER )) {
            locationProvider = LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER;
        }
        Log.w(TAG,"CurrentLocProvider :"+locationProvider);

        location=locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(locationProvider);
        Log.i(TAG,"Location :"+location);
        if(location!=null){
            Log.i(TAG,"Location Lat :"+location.getLatitude());
            latitude = Double.toString(location.getLatitude());
            longitude = Double.toString(location.getLongitude());

            txtView.append("\nLatitude : "+latitude+"\n Longitude : "+longitude);
        }
```

After some time

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
Log.i(TAG,"Lat :"+location.getLatitude();
Log.i(TAG,"Long :"+location.getLongitude();


}
```

Also giving me wrong location.Some times USA,In another device china.In Different device it is giving different results?
How can i get the currect result?

Thanks,
aare.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hm, it is very unlikely (but possible) to give you wrong coordinates - if the device GPS is not working properly.

BTW - the method getLastKnownLocation may return completely wrong data, as described in another stackoverflow question:
this location can be "out-of-date", since the method returns the location when the GPS was used the last time.

Give a look at onStatusChanged, also. You may output the status changes of the GPS to get a better vision of what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

You should also check if network location provider is enabled (users can have this disabled in settings):

```
locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)
```

Or even better: use [`LocationManager.PASSIVE_PROVIDER`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#PASSIVE_PROVIDER).

Comment: On emulator NETWORK_PROVIDER gives me Exception but on device it works but no use.

Comment: NETWORK_PROVIDER relies on cell netwok information and/or wifi-information. If you use this without connection to the mobile network & your wifi has not been mapped by Google (hidden SSID or somewhere off the beaten path) than you will get no meaningful result.

Comment: location=locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.PASSIVE_PROVIDER);

Comment: PASSIVE_PROVIDER only works if some other application is using location information. This is useful for getting location updates on a regular basis without forcing use of GPS/network.

Comment: Iam using Android level 4.LocationManager.PASSIVE_PROVIDER not included in this level